# Retain Keyboard focus on textfield when changing the background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I am changing the background image of my landing screen using the following code.

```
window.onload = function() {
setTimeout(changeBackground, 1000);
};
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/background.png';
backgrounds[1] = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/background2.png';
backgrounds[2] = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/background3.png';
backgrounds[3] = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/background4.png';
function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 3) currentBackground = 0;

    $('body').fadeOut(0, function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('body').fadeIn(0);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 3000);
}
```

Everything works well. However, in Internet explorer, when i try to enter the user name in the text box, when it changes the background image, the focus inside the textfield is lost and i need to click each time the background image is changed.

Can anyone please guide how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

You likely can overcome this by explicitly setting the focus each time the background changes.  Add the following line to your `changeBackground()` function (perhaps it should be the last line...):

`document.getElementById("...ID of text box...").focus();`

Bear in mind that this might cause another problem where the focus was changed intentionally before the background changed.  If this is possible, then what you really want to do is detect which element has the focus at the time the background changes, preserve it, than explicitly set it to that element.  That's done using the `document.activeElement` command.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, will try and revert!!

Comment: Hi i tried and got this working in all other browsers but IE, stragely this doesn't work with IE